# G-invariant polynomials for a concrete G

Tags: lie-groups, invariant-theory

The collection of matrices$$
\left( \begin{array}{lll} a^2 & 2ab &b^2 \\  ac & bc+ad & bd \\ c^2 & 2cd & d^2   \end{array} \right)$$ indexed by $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ is a subgroup of $GL(3,\mathbb{R})$ isomorphic to the group $PGL(2,\mathbb{R}).$ This subgroup, denoted $G$, acts by conjugation on $\mathfrak{gl}(3,\mathbb{R}).$

1. Are there any polynomial functions in the entries of a matrix $ A \in \mathfrak{gl}(3,\mathbb{R})$ invariant with respect to the action by conjugation with elements in $G$ and NOT invariant with respect to the action by conjugation of $GL(3,\mathbb{R})?$
2. Does the action by conjugation of G has any invariant sub-spaces except its Lie algebra (which is a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}(3,\mathbb{R})$)?

Comment: 1. In fact there are lots of polynomials invariant under conjugation by all elements of $GL_3(\mathbb{R})$, namely any polynomial in the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial. 2. You mean its Lie algebra?

Comment: @Qiaochu Thank you Qiaochu. I edited the question. In question #1 I meant invariant polynomials different from the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial. In #2 yes I meant Lie Algebra and NOT Linear Algebra.

Comment: Anyway, I recommend that you avoid thinking in terms of this explicit matrix representation and instead try to figure out what representation of $PGL_2(\mathbb{R})$ this is. It should be the symmetric square of the standard representation.